# How to store an integer value of 4 bytes in a memory of chunk which is malloced as type char

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have allocated a chunk of memory of type char and size is say 10 MB (i.e mem_size = 10 ):

```
int mem_size = 10; 
char *start_ptr;
if((start_ptr= malloc(mem_size*1024*1024*sizeof(char)))==NULL) {return -1;}
```

Now I want to store the size information in the header of the memory chunk.To make myself more clear, let's say: start_ptr = 0xaf868004 (This is the value I got from my execution, it changes every time).

Now I want to put the size information in the start of this pointer, i.e  `*start_ptr  = mem_size*1024*1024;`.

But I am not able to put this information in the `start_ptr`. I think the reason is because my ptr is of type `char` which only takes one byte but I am trying to store `int` which takes 4 bytes, is the problem .

I am not sure how to fix this problem..

Comment: Please add the code that's actually failing.

Comment: char *start_ptr;
int toCopy = mem_size*1024*1024;
if((start_ptr= malloc(mem_size*1024*1024*sizeof(char)))==NULL) {return -1;}
 //memcpy(start_ptr,&toCopy,4);
 //*((int *)start_ptr) = mem_size*1024*1024;
 //*start_ptr = 'A';
 printf("Value stored at %p is %d \n", start_ptr, *start_ptr);

I have got idea of couple of approaches from this site, one is memcpy and 2nd is type casting. But I want to get the desired value printed from the printf statement . It is always giving me 0

Comment: You need to cast start_ptr in the printf for %d: **(int*)start_ptr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to cast your `char` pointer to an `int` pointer. In two steps:

```
int *start_ptr_int = (int*)start_ptr;
*start_ptr_int = mem_size * 1024 * 1024;
```

In one step:

```
*((int*)start_ptr) = mem_size * 1024 * 1024;
```

The `(int*)` in front of your pointer name tells the compiler: "Yeah, I know this is not actually a pointer to `int`, but just pretend for the time being, okay?"

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the answer.It makes sense..but a quick question for you. How do I print the value at that address. 
If I do 
printf("%d ",*start_ptr);
It is still giving me 0 at that address..Am I making some mistake..

Comment: @Adi: you need to cast back to int in the printf too, eg. printf("%d", * ((int *)start_ptr))

Answer (score 1):

```
*((int*)start_ptr) = mem_size*1024*1024
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just memcpy the value in ...

ie

```
int toCopy = mem_size * 1024 * 1024;
memcpy( start_ptr, &toCopy, 4 );
```

You'd even be surprised how most compilers won't even make the memcpy call and will just set the value.

Comment: In this case, how do I print the value which I stored ..I am trying this method, but It is giving 0 at start_addr ..
I want to make sure that  ,the value is actually stored at that location.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without casts:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Block {
    size_t size;
    char data[];
};
#define SIZE (1024*1024)
int main()
{
    struct Block* block = malloc(sizeof(struct Block) + SIZE);
    block->size = SIZE;
    char* start_ptr = block->data;
    // ...
}
```

Or, to get the effect you want, change one line:

```
char* start_ptr = (char*)block;
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment on style: Don't do this:

```
if ((ptr=malloc()) == NULL)
```

There is nothing wrong with

```
ptr = malloc();
if (ptr == NULL) ...
```

Good programmers know what they could do with the language. Excellent programmers know why they shouldn't do it. ;)

And -1 to all posters who assume an int in C to always be 32 bits, including the OP in the thread title. An int is guaranteed to have at least 16 bits, and on 32 bit machines it is usually a safe assumption to have 32 bits, but your code may fail as soon as you move to a 64 bit machine.